# How to run Celery in Heroku.?

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I'm running a Django app on Heroku Web servers. I've a form which sends a mail to the users.

For sending the mail, I'm using Celery as the background task. When I test it locally(ie on localhost), it works fine. But when I upload the code on Heroku, it shows me **Application Error** . On having a look at `heroku logs` , it throws an error saying

```
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

Where am I going wrong? I've also installed redis as my broker_url and have included django-celery in requirements.txt file which installs the same.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Clearly tell that celery was not installed. pip install celery on heroku

Comment: But isn't celery an in-built module in Python itself?

Comment: Though, I tried installing the celery, it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just renamed my celery app, and it worked. Thats the trick.